# Looping a variable inside a function every time the function is called in python

Tags: python, loops

I want to append an excel file every time a function is called. How do I do this? For example, the first time the function is called, the phone number and text are pasted in row 2, then the next time the function is called, the phone number and text are pasted in row 3, etc. I want the "i" to change.

```
os.chdir("/Users/name/Desktop/name/name")
book = openpyxl.Workbook()
sheet = book.create_sheet("Sheet", 0)
sheet.cell(row=1, column=6).value = "Verification Code"


class func_with_memory:              
    i = 2
    def write_to_ith_excelrow(self):
    print ('i =', self.i)                
    self.i += 1



    def receive_sms(self, i):
        i = i+2
        # Sender's phone numer
        from_number = request.values.get('From')
        # Receiver's phone number - Plivo number
        to_number = request.values.get('To')
        # The text which was received
        text = request.values.get('Text')
        # Print the message
        print 'Message received - From: %s, To: %s, Text: %s' % (from_number, to_number, text)
        # send 'Text' into an excel file
        sheet.cell(row=i, column=6).value = text
        book.save("numbers.xlsx")
        return "Message received"



sms_to_xl = func_with_memory()
sms_to_xl.write_to_ith_excelrow()
```

Comment: define a `class` to encapsulate the data `i`.

Comment: Please don't vandalize your post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just use a global variable? It is good to be careful of their use, but in this case it seems completely appropriate.

```
import plivo, plivoxml
import openpyxl
from flask import Flask, request
import os

os.chdir("/Users/name/Desktop/name/name")
book = openpyxl.Workbook()
sheet = book.create_sheet("Sheet", 0)
sheet.cell(row=1, column=6).value = "Verification Code"

app = Flask(__name__)

xlsx_row_counter = 2

@app.route("/", methods=['GET','POST'])
def receive_sms():
    global xlsx_row_counter
    from_number = request.values.get('From')
    to_number = request.values.get('To')
    text = request.values.get('Text')
    print 'Message received - From: %s, To: %s, Text: %s' % (from_number, to_number, text)
    sheet.cell(row=xlsx_row_counter, column=6).value = text
    book.save("numbers.xlsx")
    xlsx_row_counter += 1
    return "Message received", 200

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080)
```

Comment: When I tried that I got : "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'xlsx_row_counter' referenced before assignment"

Comment: I just added a global statement as the first line in recieve_sms. Try that.

Comment: @AuthenticAccountz if you want to show your appreciation, mark my answer as solving your problem. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the function to manage this counting feature on its own, you would have to define a class, with your function as a member function with access to a member variable where you can store the counter value.

E.g. sth like:

```
class func_with_memory:              # define your class
    i = 1
    def write_to_ith_excelrow(self):
        print('i =', self.i)                # replace by meaningful code you want to process
        self.i += 1
```

Once defined, you can use this class:

```
In[1]: sms_to_xl = func_with_memory()       # instantiate the class

In[2]: sms_to_xl.write_to_ith_excelrow()    # first call of member function
i = 1

In[3]: sms_to_xl.write_to_ith_excelrow()    # second call
i = 2

In[4]: sms_to_xl.write_to_ith_excelrow()    # third call
i = 3
```

Comment: I tried it but I got this: receive_sms() takes exactly 2 arguments (0 given). I used " def receive_sms(self, i): "

Comment: Please note, that there is no parameter i in the function in my example, but of course you can do so; however - please post the whole code oft your class.

Comment: I guess you perhaps forgot to indent your function, so that it is a member oft the class defined above. Because then it's an independent function expecting two parameters: self and i.

Comment: I updated my original post to include the whole code. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: If i just use "def receive_sms() " I get this error: "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'i' referenced before assignment"

Comment: The class should only consist of the counter variable i and your function - exactly like in my example. That means : 1. The Flask code does not belong into the class, put it in Front oft it. 2. my example function can be deleted. It was just an example. 3. your function definition should be `def receive_sms(self):` - exactly like in my example. 4. in your main code, you should call `receive_sms()`, not my example function. 5. I don't know why you increment i by 2 in your function, but it's your code...